# What's the relation between nvidia driver, cuda driver and cuda toolkit?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

In the nvidia driver package, there is libcuda.so.

Is the cuda driver the same as nvidia driver?

And what's the relation between cuda toolkit and libcuda.so?

Comment: You may get better answers if you post this on the [NVIDIA Devtalk Forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From cuda document

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#driver-api

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#versioning-and-compatibility

It seems cuda driver is libcuda.so which is included in nvidia driver and used by cuda runtime api

Nvidia driver includes driver kernel module and user libraries.

Cuda toolkit is an SDK contains compiler, api, libs, docs, etc...