# NVIDIA driver - what does the 'toolkit' option mean?

Tags: cuda, gpu, driver, nvidia

[Not a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45293580/3834459)

When downloading NVIDIA GPU drivers, I've also been asked for some time which CUDA toolkit I prefer.

Now, what does this choice imply when downloading a driver?

As far as I know, different CUDA toolkits have different minimum drivers supporting them (also stated in the release notes), but what does this choice at the driver download page imply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is a backwards compatibility strategy for drivers with respect to CUDA toolkits.  For example, the latest driver should work with any older CUDA toolkit.  An older driver may not work with a newer CUDA toolkit.

That is a general statement of compatibility.  You can find it expressed [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html) (e.g. table 1) also.

However, each CUDA toolkit ships with a particular driver branch.  For example CUDA 10.1 ships with a 418.xx driver branch (this corresponds to the version of the GPU driver that is bundled with the CUDA toolkit installer).

So even though a 430.xx driver is compatible with and should work with CUDA 10.1, that isn't actually the driver branch that ships with CUDA 10.1

The dropdown allows you to select a driver that is in the same branch as the driver that particular CUDA toolkit was shipped with and has the highest test coverage with.

Comment: Thank you, exhaustive as usual!